# ArcGIS Desktop Associate certification

Tags: arcgis-desktop, references, certification

Does someone have any material that can help in Certification of **ArcGIS Desktop Associate**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esri provides a pretty thorough description of what a Desktop Associate should know and/or study to be ready to take the certification test.

- There's a book ([Esri ArcGIS Desktop Associate Certification Study Guide](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=236)) all about it.
- Looking at the [details for individual certification exams](http://www.esri.com/training/main/certification/certification-exams) may provide a more targeted idea of what specific subjects you must know, and therefore which you should focus on studying — a list of preparation resources is available for both the [10.1](http://downloads2.esri.com/campus/downloads/certification/TrainingResources/TrainingResourcesEADA101.pdf) and [10.3](http://downloads2.esri.com/campus/downloads/certification/TrainingResources/TrainingResourcesEADA101.pdf) Desktop Associate tests.

While it isn't mentioned in their preparation resources, I'd informally suggest that being able to navigate the Esri site to find answers to questions about their products is one of the more important skills I use regularly to work effectively with ArcGIS products.